# Wordpress Help - multiple images per page/post in the sidebar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a little trouble with wordpress, the admin needs to be able to post up to 5 images per page/post and then I need to be able spit those images out into the template.

Is there a plugin or something similar that will provide me with this functionality? I would be most grateful if any one could offer some advice, I have been able to find anything by googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should do the trick:

```
$photos = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );
```

if you need it for outside the loop then I would turn it into a function and add it to your functions.php page.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress keeps uploaded images as attachments, which are really just child posts of post_type 'attachment' in the wp_posts table.

Upload your images on the page/post/custom post type in question (The upload icon above the editor) and a 'Gallery' is created.

To display the photos you can make a widget and sidebar (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_sidebar) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)) or display them directly in the loop of your choice with the code below. This is essentially the same as using the [[gallery] shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) directly in the post content.

```
<?php 
    //Gather the child posts (attachments) of mime type 'image'
    $photos = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );

    //If there are any attachments..
    if (!empty($photos)) :
        //Loop through each attachment..
        foreach ($photos as $photo_id => $photo) : 
            //And render the <img> tag
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($photo_id, 'full') ;
        endforeach ;
    endif ;
?>
```